# rewritten the Gompertz finction

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Why can I rewrite this equation:

$$\frac{dN}{dt}=rN ln(\frac{K}{N})$$

as

$$\frac{d}{dt}[ln(\frac{N}{K} )] = r(-1)[ln(\frac{N}{K})] $$

I have tried:

I know that since I can do 
$$rNln(\frac{K}{N})=(-r)N ln(\frac{N}{K})$$

I have

$$\frac{dN}{dt}=(-r)N ln(\frac{N}{K})$$

but I don't understand why they eliminated N.

I appreciate any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from
$$
\frac{dN}{dt}=rN \ln(\frac{K}{N})
$$
we know that 
$$
\frac{1}{N}\frac{dN}{dt}= -r \ln(\frac{N}{K})
\implies
\frac{1}{N/K}\frac{d (N/K)}{dt}= -r \ln(\frac{N}{K})
\implies
\frac{d}{dt} ( \ln \frac{N}{K} ) = -r \ln(\frac{N}{K}).
$$

Answer (score 1):

The chain rule implies that for any function $N(t)$, we have $$\frac{d}{dt} \ln(N(t)) = \frac{1}{N(t)} \frac{dN}{dt}.$$

From there, $$\frac{d}{dt} \ln(\frac{N}{K}) = \frac{1}{N/K} \frac{d}{dt}(\frac{N}{K}) = \frac{1}{N} \frac{dN}{dt}.$$

So take your last line, divide both sides by $N$, and substitute $\frac{d}{dt}\ln(\frac{K}{N})$ for $\frac{1}{N}\frac{dN}{dt}$.

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{d}{dt}\log(N)=\frac{1}{N}\frac{dN}{dt}$